# Flyway SQL Server database migration failed using statement delimiter GO

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, flyway

When I used create view script with GO delimeter as following, flyway migration is failed.

My script:

```
DROP VIEW dbo.TESTVIEW
GO  
CREATE VIEW dbo.TESTVIEW AS (SELECT T1.* from dbo.TEST as T1)
GO
```

Fail log:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>
> Error executing statement at line 1: DROP VIEW dbo.TESTVIEW GO  CREATE VIEW dbo.TESTVIEW AS (SELECT T1.* from dbo.TEST as T1) GO
>
> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:216)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1515)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:792)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:689)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:5696)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Simple: don't use `GO` which is *not* a SQL statement, but simply a **separator** that SQL Server Management Studio and `SQLCMD` know - but it's not part of any SQL standard...

Comment: Flyway supports GO as a delimiter. This should work. Please file an issue in the Flyway issue tracker with more details (make sure to be on Flyway 3.0 first)